# NoClassDefFoundError: in Google App Engine app while creating Gson instance

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gson, noclassdeffounderror

Is there something tricky about using Gson in Google App Engine App? I placed gson jar in war/lib and included it in the build path. I'm using Eclipse.

Code compiles however app keeps failing at line:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

with:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
```

Comment: I'm not near a laptop that has the GAE Eclipse environment set up, but I recall having to edit the Project definition to tell it about gson.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I placed library under war/libs and not under war/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: You did not tell me if your project is a Java EE project (It calls them Dynamic Web Project). But if so, like a think, letting Eclipse manage your deploy will avoid this kind of problems in future.

Comment: I did not, because I'm totally new to web development :) I'm native Android, iOS developer

Answer (score 1):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` specifies that you have a particular class available at compile time but missing or not initialized during runtime. In your case `com/google/gson/Gson` class is found at compile time as gson jar is in your lib. But during runtime it is either not present or not initialized. Check for a conflict of gson jar or if there is an `ExceptionInInitializerError` in the stacktrace. You may further understand it here - [Debugging a NoClassDefFoundError](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know GAE by name only, but I have that kind of error in Eclipse when I have a dynamic web project and I forget to deploy libs I used to build.

So, maybe you can solve by going into Deployment Assembly section of your project and add libs that you have in your build path.

Comment: where is that section exactly?

Comment: Right click on project name on Navigator or Project Explorer. Usually is third option. Pay attention that you must have a Dynamic Web Project  as kind of project.